# PnP Powershell syntax question

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

Can someone explain what the % symbol represents in this code snippet?

Perhaps you could point me to that documentation?

```
if($Recurse -eq $false){
    Get-PnPSubWebs | % {
        PopulateData -web $_ -incldeFileSize $IncludeFileSize                   
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It's short for "Foreach-object" in PowerShell. However, it has nothing to do with SharePoint or the PNP Framework so this is more of a programing question! https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

"%" is a PowerShell alias for ForEach / ForEach-Object. In PowerShell type Get-Alias for a list.

PS C:> Get-Alias

```
CommandType     Name
-----------     ----
Alias           % -> ForEach-Object
Alias           ? -> Where-Object
Alias           ac -> Add-Content
Alias           asnp -> Add-PSSnapin
Alias           cat -> Get-Content
Alias           cd -> Set-Location
...
```